# Comando Less para leer el archivo contenido

Tags: línea-de-comandos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trato de conseguir el nombre del archivo pero me dice que no suchj file or directory que puedo hacer alguien me puede ayudar por favor

Comment: no se como se llama el archivo ni idea de lo quieras hacer pero debes adjuntar  el resultado del comando `ls` :v no obstante si no sabes como se llama el archivo puedes escribir la primera letra y darle al tecla `tab` y completara si no doble `tab` mostrara todos lo que empiezen con esa letra colocas otra y asi sucesivamente hasta que complete!